# iOS all viewcontroller transitions breaks (0 time animations)

Tags: ios, uianimation

My App viewcontrollers transitions breaks after using the App for some time. The transitions still happens but the animations is done in 0 time. Status bar, navigationbar and tabbar hide animations also starts happen in 0 time.

A few animatons, like spinners and fade is still working.

I get no exceptions when this problem starts. Does anyone know what is happening ?

Comment: What code are you using to do push the view controllers?

Comment: Your question is too generic. Be more descriptive, provide the code, provide as much information as possible - read how to use stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Its a storyboard arc project, containing old style nib/xib. So using storyboard segue and for 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

The problem is that I cant track down what code causing the different animations/transitions to break. Sometimes it happens after using the app for 10 sec, other time 10 min. Also I have not been able to pinpoint what action starts this problem. 

I dont think its the transitions that's the problem. I think its some other code or lib that's break the animations in all views in the app.

Comment: FWIW, I've seen all of my animations break as well and been unable to find the code that causes it. How do you know the transitions are still happening? I thought my problem may have been calling UIKit functions on background threads so I installed a guard to check, but no luck. Here's the guard I used: https://gist.github.com/steipete/5664345